# Youtube Video Crash Xcode ios6

Tags: iphone, ios, ios6, uiwebview, youtube

In `UIWebview` when I try to play any video on the `youtube` it crash my xcode ,I am using iOS6 .. I simply used the `UIWebview` with loading url youtube to it...do I need to embeddd mediaplayer to play the videos?

what more i need to do to play the video on the youtube in `UIWebView`

**code**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];


 NSString *newVersionHTML = @"<html>\
<style>body{padding:0;margin:0;}</style>\
<iframe width=\"%0.0f\" height=\"%0.0f\" src=\"http://www.youtube.com/embed/%@?modestbranding=1;title=;showinfo=0;rel=0;controls=0\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe>\
</html>";

  NSString *htmlToLoad = [NSString stringWithFormat:newVersionHTML, webView.frame.size.width, webView.frame.size.height,videoId];
 [webView loadHTMLString:htmlToLoad baseURL:nil];
 webView.delegate = self;
// self.webView.mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction = NO;


webView=[[UIWebView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 768)];


[self.webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.youtube.com/"]]]];
 [self.view addSubview:webView];

}
```

**new error**

```
2013-02-13 11:08:20.902 webview[593:c07] [MPAVController] Autoplay: Enabling autoplay
2013-02-13 11:08:20.903 webview[593:c07] [MPAVController] Autoplay: Skipping autoplay, disabled (for current item: 0, on player: 1)
2013-02-13 11:08:20.903 webview[593:c07] setting movie path: http://r4---sn-ci5gupcc-cage.c.youtube.com/videoplayback?el=watch&itag=18&cp=U0hVRVdQVF9IU0NONV9PSlhFOl9xb2x5ZzMxX3Zw&sver=3&expire=1360756439&yms=_tpjcd07_wk&signature=0659B5710FD8503E5AA5059CE35A9754DD59B90F.5194D7A1B0EC8749FC91CC1B31261B81950E801E&upn=Y8J9bVD4jLE&newshard=yes&ratebypass=yes&sparams=cp%2Cid%2Cip%2Cipbits%2Citag%2Cratebypass%2Csource%2Cupn%2Cexpire&ipbits=8&source=youtube&id=748bf802989d33fb&app=youtube_mobile&key=yt1&ip=122.179.77.11&fexp=906335%2C901802%2C909917%2C910207%2C914052%2C916613%2C901446%2C920704%2C912806%2C902000%2C922403%2C922405%2C929901%2C913605%2C925710%2C929114%2C925006%2C908529%2C920201%2C911116%2C926403%2C910221%2C901451%2C919114&dnc=1&mt=1360733832&mv=m&ms=au&cpn=dxlJMMz5hJkR_ARd&ptk=Radaantv&oid=bGpsJKyLNbnXo_1YohiEiw&ptchn=RadaanMedia&pltype=content
2013-02-13 11:08:20.904 webview[593:c07] [MPAVController] Autoplay: Enabling autoplay
2013-02-13 11:08:20.908 webview[593:c07] [MPCloudAssetDownloadController] Prioritization requested for media item ID: 0
2013-02-13 11:08:23.974 webview[593:8817]  <0xb057e000> Error '!obj' trying to fetch default input device's sample rate
2013-02-13 11:08:23.974 webview[593:8817]  <0xb057e000> Error getting audio input device sample rate: '!obj'
2  013-02-13 11:08:23.975 webview[593:8817]  <0xb057e000> AQMEIOManager::FindIOUnit: error 'NoHW'
2013-02-13 11:08:23.975 webview[593:c07]  <com.apple.main-thread> AQMEIOManager::FindIOUnit: error 'NoHW'
2013-02-13 11:08:24.567 webview[593:c07]  <com.apple.main-thread> AQMEIOManager::FindIOUnit: error 'NoHW'
2013-02-13 11:08:24.567 webview[593:c07]  <com.apple.main-thread> AQMEIOManager::FindIOUnit: error 'NoHW'
2013-02-13 11:08:24.569 webview[593:c07]  <com.apple.main-thread> AQMEIOManager::FindIOUnit: error 'NoHW'
```

Comment: from this example you are loading youtube.com not a video.

Comment: your code is working for me....

Comment: @JohnRiselvato ok what code do i need to load video??

Comment: @Sudha ya It works fine to load youtube but crashes when I load video

Answer (score 1):

Just pass videoId of youtube video in the below code to play youtube videos

for example if link is http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DTbgpJAggg0&feature=youtube_gdata then

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
   [super viewDidLoad];

   webView=[[UIWebView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 768)];

   [self.view addSubview:self.webView];

   self.webView.delegate = self;


   NSString *newVersionHTML = @"<html>\
<style>body{padding:0;margin:0;}</style>\
<iframe width=\"%0.0f\" height=\"%0.0f\" src=\"http://www.youtube.com/embed/%@?modestbranding=1;title=;showinfo=0;rel=0;controls=0\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe>\
</html>";

    NSString *htmlToLoad = [NSString stringWithFormat:newVersionHTML, self.webView.frame.size.width, self.webView.frame.size.height,videoId];
    [self.webView loadHTMLString:htmlToLoad baseURL:nil];

}
```

simply to OPEN youtube homepage in webview use:

In .h :

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIWebView *webView;
```

In .m :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    _webView=[[UIWebView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 768)];

    [self.view addSubview:self.webView];

    self.webView.delegate = self;


    [self.webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.youtube.com/"]]]];

}
```

Comment: videoId is the NSString and you can get video Id from youtube url to play video

Comment: for example EDTTqtO-y2I is a videoId

Comment: ya done but didnt work again it crash ..check `New Error `in code

Comment: ya man ! i simply pasted ur code in my code...u check in the question part

Comment: the code you gave me `[webView loadHTMLString:htmlToLoad baseURL:nil];`  i think this is for any particular video ..it sets the frame ...

Comment: no man .it will load particularly single video..my default home page would be youtube..and then i should be able to play any video

Comment: what are you trying to do ? Open youtube in webpage just it ??

Comment: ya simply want to open ."youtube home page" in webpage and play any video by select..

Comment: yaar yeh to mere ko bi pata h..how to load url ...ok fine...now youtube will open ok..but when i will open any video...vo load ni hogi vo xcode crash car degi...

Comment: i just created a new project and used this code and its working without crash

Comment: what i want is ...youtube load ho....and u should be able to watch ..play anyyy video.... not just one..just like normal browser

Comment: na...the video is currently unavailable..is coming..bcz we have not given any video url to play in code

Comment: seee buddy either 1. You can use google api's to get jSON data for youtube videos and get youtube video ID and use the first code in answer OR 2.) Open youtube as in the second part of the answer 
.. these two are different things you can not mix them up

Comment: may be we can do a trick.. use webViewDidStartLoad: function and catch the URL extract youtube video from it and again reload the webview using the ID code 1st part of the answer...

Comment: ok..pehle yeh batao...the answer which is 1st...usse video play to  ho  hi nai rai h as...humne sirf `src=\"http://www.youtube.com/embed/%@?` diya h koi link thodi diya h...and if i give `http://www.youtube.com/embed/DTbgpJAggg0` it also crash

Comment: seeeee buddyyyyy 1. the first code is to embed a youtube video in a webview it doesnt need the youtube link..its a iframe embedded in webview to play youtube video

Comment: so dont give the direct embed url to play in webview use the full HTML string only

Comment: just try this code http://www.mightymeta.co.uk/embedding-youtube-within-iphone-apps/ is it works fine for you?>?

Comment: he did the same thing buddyyy and one more thing youtube videos are playing using the simple method just open youtube in webview, some videos wont play and some will play

Comment: ya thing is that ...if i run this same source code ..this will also crash **when i play the video**.. is it bcz of iOS 6??

Comment: if its code is crashing then use mine :) Use the one which needs ID

Comment: check u check this code...which i edited with your code...y it is not working.. http://www.2shared.com/file/piRVd8Da/VideoLauncher-1.html

Comment: ya not crashing even on mine...but y is not video is playing...video is coming unavailable..but link is been given `http://youtube.com/embed/-0Xa4bHcJu8`  in VideoLauncherViewController.h

Comment: yeah since IOS 6 came, youtube videos can be played using iFrame and most of the videos are unable to play using this method .. some old methods are there but available for OS less than IOS 6.0 version

Comment: and on simulator youtube videos wont be run..ryt? as it does not support the plugin